Is this PCIe to M.2 adapter good to attach Google Coral AI M.2 Accelerator A+E key
I wanted to connect a Google Coral AI M.2 Accelerator A+E key Edge TPU device to Raspberry Pi 5 to run an object detection model on it (which I ordered from this link), I ordered Coolwell for Raspberry Pi 5 PCIe to M.2 adapter from this link to connect coral TPU to PCIe on raspberry pi 5.
However, after connecting these two devices, the TPU is not detected to run the AI model.
The question I have is whether those hardware are good to work together, Did I choose a good Adapter for that purpose?

Welcome.  You should probably be explicit about how the "TPU is not detected to run the AI model".

talk to Coolwell tech support

@goldilocks The Coral TPU was not listed when running the lspci command. Also, the TPU was not fitting properly.

If by "the TPU was not fitting properly" you mean it doesn't insert into the M.2 slot properly that seems pretty relevant -- please edit this information into your question, and include a photograph of the connection if possible.

I have that HAT! It uses an M key for its M.2 socket so you'd need to get M key sticks or B+M key sticks. I'm 99% sure that A+E won't work on that HAT. I have used mine to boot my Pi from NVME (super fast) but I have the Coral B+M stick so hopefully it works! Good luck!
