Waveshare PCIe to M.2 adapter with Transcend TS1TMTS425S
I am trying to install a PCIe HAT from Waveshare with the Transcend M.2 SSD TS1TMTS425S.

I have enabled PCIe in /boot/firmware/config.txt:
$ sed -n '/^\[all\]/,$p' /boot/firmware/config.txt                                                                                                                                         
[all]
dtparam=pciex1

But lspci does not show the SSD:
$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 2712 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Device 1de4:0001

What can be wrong?

Hmm... Although this question (and the ad on amazon.se) refers to the hat as "Coolwell", if you look at the ad link you can see it is the same Waveshare hat, similar problem (device not shown in lspci):   https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/is-this-pcie-to-m-2-adapter-good-to-attach-google-coral-ai-m-2-accelerator-ae-k
